# How awful is the awful magician?

Tags: probability, expected-value

There is a magician (who is totally not me), who shuffles a standard deck of cards (52 cards, four suits). A volunteer from the crowds chooses a card at random, reinserts into the package, and reshuffles.

The awful magician, being awful, starts from the top of the pack.

"Is this your card?"
"No."

The next card, and the question repeats. On and on, until finally, the volunteer's card reveals itself. Much to the excitement of everyone, that they get to go home.

---

In this scenario, which is totally not based on real life, what is the expected value of attempts by the awful magician before they manage to bedazzle their audience?

Just to make things slightly more mathematical, the volunteer picks a card at random, then reshuffles the pack. So the question can be recast as given a number $n$ between $1$ and $52$, and a permutation $\pi$ of $\{1,\dots,52\}$, what is the expected value for $\pi^{-1}(n)$?

(The questions comes from playing with a deck of cards, and thinking about Michael Stevens' [Vsauce video](https://youtu.be/ObiqJzfyACM?t=14m44s) regarding card tricks, where he cites Scott Czepiel about $52!$.)

Comment: It should be the average of the numbers from 1 to 52 since everything is invariant under relabelling the cards, right?  Please tell me I'm not Monty Halling myself somehow...

Comment: Daniel, I have negative understanding of probability and expectations (in particular). So...

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Please post that as an (the) answer. Symmetry wins.

Comment: As a way to get intuition:  if the answer were greater than half the average, you could speed things up by starting from the bottom of the deck.

Comment: @lulu: Well, that makes sense. But it's a terrible magician. :)

Comment: @lulu You didn't mean "half the average", did you?

Comment: @bof  Certainly not.  I had just got through typing $\frac 12$ elsewhere, so I had "half" on the brain.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable denoting the number of attempts made.  Note that $Pr(X=k)=\frac{1}{52}$ for every $k\in\{1,2,3,\dots,52\}$.  Continue the approach by the definition of expected value.

$E[X]=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{52}kPr(X=k) = \frac{1}{52}\sum\limits_{k=1}^{52}k=\frac{1}{52}\cdot\frac{52\cdot53}{2}=\frac{53}{2}$

Comment: I'd feel embarrassed that it ended up being this simple, but I'm sufficiently confident in my inability to grasp basic concepts of probability. Especially when it means finite computations.

Answer (score 10):

There are 52 total cards, and the distribution of the card-of-interest is invariant under reversing the shuffled deck. So the expected value of the number of cards seen (including the card-of-interest) satisfies $x=53-x$, giving $x=53/2$.